# How to format a JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, morris.js

I have below method to calculate every month income and expenses.

```
$query = Transaction::whereYear('date', $year)
                ->groupBy([DB::raw('MONTH(date)'),'type'])->get([DB::raw('MONTH(date) as month'), DB::raw('SUM(amount) as value'), 'type'])
                ->toJSON();
```

After gotten the JSON data I want to populate them into Morris Bar Chart.

Below is the JSON format,

```
[{"month":11,"value":102.23,"type":"In"},{"month":11,"value":133.9,"type":"Out"}]
```

However, it doesn't fit the Morris data format. How can I twist the JSON into below?

[{"month":11,"In":102.23,"Out":133.9}]

```
$(function() {
  var chart = Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: [0, 0], 
    xkey: 'Month',
    ykeys: ['In', 'Out'], 
    labels: ['In','Out'], 
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
  });
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "./getMonthlyOverview"
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      chart.setData(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert( "error occured" );
    });
});
```

I tried to change my query to below:

```
$stats = DB::select("select month,  SUM(IF( type = 'In', amount, 0)) as Income,  SUM(IF( type = 'Out', amount, 0)) as Expense from "
                . "(SELECT MONTH(date) as month, type, SUM(amount) as amount FROM Transactions WHERE YEAR(date) = " . $year . " group by MONTH(date), type) as c "
                . "group by month");
```

Not sure is it a good solution.

Comment: Restruct result array and after that - apply `json_encod`ing

Comment: Add a custom function to fill `data` field of the chart in your JS code. So you can iterate over the date and fill the charts the way you want.

Comment: Looks like your query needs a "pivot"  I don't Laravel, so I don't know if it has a handy pivot function/syntax.

Comment: So will your actual input data be 12x larger?  Or are you only dealing with one month at a time?

Comment: Will be at most 12 months. I am dealing with one year at a time, then group by months and calculating the total expenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only dealing with one month's data, then you don't need to call any clever functions because your data structure is predictable.  Just manually restructure.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2746fb933cc75efac1064efa13ca0c50efb882a))

```
$json = '[{"month":11,"value":102.23,"type":"In"},{"month":11,"value":133.9,"type":"Out"}]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo json_encode(['month' => $array[0]['month'], $array[0]['type'] => $array[0]['value'], $array[1]['type'] => $array[1]['value']]);
```

Output:

```
{"month":11,"In":102.23,"Out":133.9}
```

---

If you are dealing with multiple months in a single set, you will just need to iterate the resultset, substitute the hardcoded `[0]` and `[1]` keys above for paired variables: 0 & 1 together, 2 & 3, etc.

---

**UPDATE**: If you are happy to write a custom mysql query, then this should do:

```
$stats = DB::select("
    SELECT `month`,
           SUM(IF(`type` = 'In', amount, 0)) AS Income,
           SUM(IF(`type` = 'Out', amount, 0)) AS Expense
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE YEAR(`date`) = " . (int)$year . "
    GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)
");
```

Comment: @WynnTeo  If one of the answers has resolved your question, please award the green tick.  All pages should progress to a system-recognized resolution.  If neither of the answers is suitable please leave comments to the volunteers to clarify what is not quite right.

Comment: Because my data is dynamically generated, I can't use this way to format.

Comment: Please explain how your data may vary and I'll adjust.

Comment: Will be at most 12 months. I am dealing with one year at a time, then group by months and calculating the total expenses.

Comment: Please update your question to express what a realistic, larger set of data will look like and then state your exact desired output for that sample data.

Comment: @WynnTeo I've added a simpler query that should sufficiently pivot your data.  If this doesn't work, please create an sqlfiddle of your data, so that we can test our solutions.  Please progress this page to a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you can decode your JSON and if you pass `true` as the second parameter, you will have an associative array. Now, create a `$result` `array` which will be empty at the start and you will fill the result(s) there. Now, iterate through the decoded JSON, parse the results and fill `$result` with them. When this is finished, convert `$result` to JSON using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and this should solve the problem.